# tool to view the compiler generated code

Tags: c#

Does anybody know tools to view the C# compiler generated code for delegate?

I want to verify the following

```
class X
{
     public event D Ev;
}
```

Which is compiled to :

```
class X
{
     private D __Ev;  // field to hold the delegate

     public event D Ev {
           add {
                lock(this) { __Ev = __Ev + value; }
           }

           remove {
                lock(this) { __Ev = __Ev – value; }
           }
     }
}
```

Comment: `delegate` is a keyword, not a function.  What code do you want to see?

Comment: You should accept answers for your questions.

Comment: Note that we've slightly changed the codegen for events in C# 4. You might be *disconfirming* that codegen.

Comment: @SLaks: how? The same way we make any change to the language. We edit the compiler's source code and fire up MSBuild. Why? Because that "lock this" is a bad programming practice, for one reason. There are other reasons but they won't fit into 500 characters. I'll do a blog post on it one of these days.

Comment: @Eric: I meant `how was it changed?` (What were the changes?).

Comment: @SLaks: Here's Chris's article on why this is bad: http://blogs.msdn.com/cburrows/archive/2008/02/18/field-like-events-considered-harmful.aspx -- Chris made some changes to the codegen of field-like events for C# 4 to address these problems but the details are way, way too complicated for a 500 character comment. One of us will blog about it at some point.

Comment: @SLaks: I talked with Chris about this over lunch. He already has a whole series of articles planned for later this year to discuss the change, what possible breaking changes it introduces, and so on.  Watch his blog for details.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your question makes no sense, but you're probably looking for [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/).

**EDIT**: Now, your question does make sense.  You're still looking for Reflector.
However, you'll need to set the Optimization to None in options.

It reveals,

```
private EventHandler<MyEventArgs> MyEvent;
public event EventHandler<MyEventArgs> MyEvent
{
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)] add
    {
        this.MyEvent = (EventHandler<MyEventArgs>) Delegate.Combine(this.MyEvent, value);
        return;
    }
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)] remove
    {
        this.MyEvent = (EventHandler<MyEventArgs>) Delegate.Remove(this.MyEvent, value);
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Reflector was bought by RedGate and is now a commercial product.

A free alternative is dotPeek:

https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/

It's a very capable decompiler with plenty of options and every bit as good as Reflector was at the time it was purchased. I haven't used it since so can't comment on what you get for your money.

---

Another tool is LINQPad:

http://www.linqpad.net/

It disassembles C# as you type (which is handy) and will show you the CIL. However it won't attempt to decompile that back into C# for you.