# How methods of delegate type are generated internally?

Tags: c#, delegates

I know delegate type is inherited from MulticastDelegate which is in turn inherited from Delegate class.

Also when we create delegate instance it creates three methods (Invoke, BeginInvoke, EndInvoke apart from constructor) with the same signature of the delegate.

I am not able to understand how it is created internally(methods with delegate type signature)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is it created - the code is emitted by the C# compiler.  What more do you need to know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets say for example, we have a delegate like this:

```
public delegate int BinaryOp(int x, int y);
```

How does the compiler know how to define the Invoke(), BeginInvoke(), and
EndInvoke() methods?

This is the generated class by the compiler:

```
sealed class BinaryOp : System.MulticastDelegate
{
public BinaryOp(object target, uint functionAddress);
public int Invoke(int x, int y);
public IAsyncResult BeginInvoke(int x, int y,AsyncCallback cb, object state);
public int EndInvoke(IAsyncResult result);
}
```

First, notice that the parameters and return value defined for the Invoke() method exactly
match the definition of the BinaryOp delegate.

The initial parameters to BeginInvoke() members (two integers in our case) are also based on the BinaryOp delegate;
however, BeginInvoke() will always provide two final parameters (of type AsyncCallback and object) that are used to facilitate asynchronous method invocations.

Finally, the return value of EndInvoke() is identical to the original
delegate declaration and will always take as a sole parameter an object implementing the
IAsyncResult interface.

Comment: You mean to say compiler will take care of generating the methods with right parameters?

Comment: Yes. The compiler will look at the return type and parameters of the delegate, and creates the methods accordingly. For example if the two parameters where of type char, the methods in the generated class will have parameters of type char.

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189342/tool-to-view-the-compiler-generated-code

Answer (score 4):

If you have a look at the IL of a delegate type in Reflector or ILSpy, you'll see that it looks something like this:

```
.class public sealed System.Action extends System.MulticastDelegate
{
    .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname instance void .ctor(object 'object', native int 'method') runtime managed {}

    .method public hidebysig newslot virtual instance void Invoke() runtime managed {}

    .method public hidebysig newslot virtual instance class System.IAsyncResult BeginInvoke(class System.AsyncCallback callback, object 'object') runtime managed {}

    .method public hidebysig newslot virtual instance void EndInvoke(class System.IAsyncResult result) runtime managed {}
}
```

that is, a constructor (`.ctor`), `Invoke`, and `BeginInvoke/EndInvoke` methods. You'll also notice that these methods have no implementation (the method bodies are empty), and are marked with `runtime`.

The `runtime` keyword indicates to the CLR that this method needs an implementation supplied by the CLR itself. That is, the implementation of a delegate is entirely Magic inside the CLR itself. When a delegate type is loaded, the CLR notices that it derives from `System.Delegate`, notices the `runtime` flag, and so creates implementations of those methods inside the CLR for that specific delegate type.

What those implementations actually look like is entirely up to the CLR you're running it on (whether the .NET platform, Mono, or something else), but is likely to be in native code directly.

When a compiler compiles a delegate type, it simply creates these method stubs to match this pattern expected by the CLR, and leaves it at that. How a delegate actually works is up to the runtime.